# Design changes in one database reflecting in another database in azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL Database. I want to copy all the tables from my `Production_Database` to a `Backup_Database`.

Both the databases are using the same server and same azure subscription.
I have built ADF pipelines to move data from `Production_Database` to `Backup_Database` and they are doing a fine job.

Now, my supervisor says that when we change the Design of a table in `Production_Database` e.g. add a new column in a table, this design change should also reflect in the `Backup_Database`. I am not able to figure out that how can I achieve this.

I tried using :

```
CREATE DATABASE Backup_Database AS COPY OF Production_Database;
```

This command will copy all the tables and the data present in the Production Database.

Now, The problem is that the `Backup_Database` created with the above command will have same number of DTUs as the `Production_Database`. I do not want to use the same number of DTUs in `Backup_Database` as it is very costly.

In a nutshell, in my `Backup_Database` should automatically reflect the design changes done in `Production_Database`

Do we have any other solution?

Comment: Sounds like you need some kind of source control, so that you can deploy DDL scripts to both production and backup.

Comment: Yep, deployment automation would be the key to allowing you to make changes show up on both databases at the same time. If you only ever do SQL Server, SQL Server Database Tools could help. However, if you multiple platforms, and who doesn't, I'd suggest looking at Flyway: https://flywaydb.org/